# Python: Random trivia trivia question/answer, in parameters

Tags: python

I am new to learning python and want to run bit of a trivia. Basically, I want to ask a random question from a list and then using an 'in' operator, figure if the user input of Y/N is correct or not. I'm stuck with determining how to check whether it is correct or not. Maybe my (incorrect) code can explain better.

```
import random

Players = ['Patrice Evra', 'Rio Ferdinand', 'Sergio Ramos', 'Gerard Pique']
Clubs = ['Manchester United', 'Nice', 'Monaco', 'Marseille', 'West Ham United', 'Sevilla', 'Real Madrid', 'Barcelona']
Ramos = ['Sevilla', 'Real Madrid']
Evra = ['Manchester United', 'Nice', 'Monaco', 'Marseille', 'West Ham United']
Ferdinand = ['Leeds United', 'Manchester United']
Pique = ['Barcelona', 'Manchester United']
print('Did ' + random.choice(Players) + ' play for ' + random.choice(Clubs) + ' ? Y/N')
answer = input()
```

This is where I'm stuck and not even sure if this is the right way to go about this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'll leave the answer to @Camaendir below, but just wanted to let you know of a cleaner method to concatenate strings as of Python 3.6: [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) i.e. `print(f"Did {player} play for {club}?")`. Additionally, input can receive a str argument to pre-pend to the input area e.g. `answer = input('Y/N')`.

Comment: @Dbercules Thank you. Had completely forgotten about this method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most importantly you have to save your random choice so you can verify it later. So you should asign two variables before:

```py
player = random.choice(Players)
club = random.choice(Clubs)
print('Did ' + player + ' play for ' + club + ' ? Y/N')
```

Then you can verify that yourself via if statements. But a faster (more complex) way would be:

```py
did_play = club in [Evra, Ferdinand, Ramos, Pique][Players.index(player)]
```

It would be better to store the variables `Evra`, `Ferdinand`, `Ramos` and `Pique`  differently, but for now that should to the trick.

A better way to store those variables would be in a dictionary like such:

```py
player_clubs = {
"Patrice Evra": ['Manchester United', 'Nice', 'Monaco', 'Marseille', 'West Ham United'],
"Rio Ferdinand": ['Leeds United', 'Manchester United'],
"Sergio Ramos": ['Sevilla', 'Real Madrid'],
"Gerard Pique": ['Barcelona', 'Manchester United']
}
```

That way you can easier check if they played in a certain club like:

```py
did_play = club in player_clubs[player]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried this method but it is picking up two values with the question. So the prompt, for example, is: "Did Gerard Pique play for ['Barcelona', 'Manchester United']? y/n: "

Answer (score 2):

You need to associate a player with a club.  This is best done with a dictionary, which I call clubs here.  The keys of this dictionary are the club names and the values are a list of players in each club.  Also, when you ask for user input, you should put your prompt question within the argument of the input.

```
import random
players = ['Patrice Evra', 'Rio Ferdinand', 'Sergio Ramos', 'Gerard Pique']
clubs = {'Manchester United':['Patrice Evra', 'Rio Ferdinand', 'Gerard Pique'],
   'Nice':['Patrice Evra'],
   'Monaco':['Patrice Evra'],
   'Marseille':['Patrice Evra'],
   'West Ham United':['Patrice Evra'],
   'Sevilla':['Sergio Ramos'],
   'Real Madrid':['Sergio Ramos'],
   'Barcelona':['Gerard Pique'],
   'Leeds Nations': ['Rio Ferdinand']}

player = random.choice(players)
club = random.choice(list(clubs.keys()))
answer = input(f'Did {player} play for {club}? y/n: ')
if answer == "y" and player in clubs[club]\
        or answer == "n" and player not in clubs[club]:
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print("wrong")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is way to generate the questions out of one dictionary. I realize some of the code might be a bit confusing if you have just begun coding, but it will provide you some interesting stuff to look into.

```
import random

#Store all clubs per player in a dictionary
games_dict = {"Sergio Ramos": ['Sevilla', 'Real Madrid'], "Patrice Evra": ['Manchester United', 'Nice', 'Monaco', 'Marseille', 'West Ham United'], 
"Rio Ferdinand": ['Leeds United', 'Manchester United'], "Gerard Pique": ['Barcelona', 'Manchester United']}
#Get a list of player in the dictionary
players = list(games_dict.keys())
#Get a list of clubs in the dictionary using a list comprehension
clubs =  [club for clublist in games_dict.values() for club in clublist]
#Select random player
player = random.choice(players)
#Get a random club (set is used to only select from unique clubs)
club = random.choice(list(set(clubs)))
#Ask for answer
inputanswer = input(f"Did {player} play for {club}? Y/N")

#Check if answer is correct
if inputanswer.lower() == "y" and club in games_dict[player] or inputanswer.lower() == "n" and club not in games_dict[player]:
    print("correct!")
else:
    print("incorrect!")
```